# What is the easiest way to create an HTML mouseover tool tip?

Tags: html, tooltip

What is the easiest, cleanest way to create an HTML mouseover tool tip without using JavaScript?

```
<img id=Pennstate src="/blah" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

mouse over that and have a a nice tooltip "We are Pennstate!"

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the native [HTML `title` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#the-title-attribute):

```html
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"
     style="cursor:pointer;"
     title="Stack Overflow">
```

But if you need more, try the [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) widget provided by jQuery UI since version 1.9.

Comment: The 'title' attribute also works in <span> elements, so you can easily display a simple mouse-over tooltip over text.

Comment: Don't do this! It's not accessible for keyboard or screen reader users. More info: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/dont-rely-title-attribute-accessibility-seo and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role

Answer (score 33):

If you don't care much what the tooltip looks like you can always just use the "title" attribute

Comment: Don't do this! It's not accessible for keyboard or screen reader users. More info: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/dont-rely-title-attribute-accessibility-seo and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role

Answer (score 8):

You may use a pseudoelement as a tooltip, setting its content from a data property using the css [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function.

```css
[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
  padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="We are Pennstate!">Pennstate</div>
```

Comment: A nice solution, I like that its treating the tooltip as data about the item, rather than a secondary item that just happens to appear like it belongs.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt' work on enbedded SVG files...

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest... all browsers now seem to have tooltips so they can interpret from the HTML directly:

```
      <span title={timezoneOffset} data-toggle="tooltip">
        {timeZoneAbbreviation}
      </span>
```

- Title: Text for Tooltip
- data-toggle: Tells the browser what to do
  with it

Comment: This seems to be a feature of Bootstrap, not pure HTML

Comment: Title is the browser part. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp